# Set random number in css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS style sheet which contains the code below:

```
.content1{position:fixed;top:70px;left:70px;}
.content2{position:fixed;top:50px;left:150px;}
.content3{position:fixed;top:115px;left:190px;}
.content4{position:fixed;top:170px;left:190px;}
.content5{position:fixed;top:200px;left:110px;}
.content6{position:fixed;top:140px;left:40px;}
```

Whenever a user clicks a button, this number (1-6) should be set randomly. The idea is to place each div at different places

How can i change it every time when user clicks a button

```
$(function() {
      $('#btn2').click(function() {

         var classes = ["content1", "content2", "content3", "content4", "content5", "content6"];
    $("#content").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });

      });
    });
```

Comment: ok i have added the code. But still not working. Can you pls help me?

Comment: You wrote that complete implementation in 7 minutes? Why not spend a couple more to check why it doesn't work? Have you tried logging the generated index? Maybe it contains a weird value (say, a floating point value). In that case you would probably get an error in the console too, which would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to move it around randomly, why not change the top and left locations? For example...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#btn2').click(function() {

   // adding 0.5 to random to ensure it at least moves a bit
  var top = Math.round((Math.random() + 0.5) * 100 + 50);
  var left = Math.round((Math.random() + 0.5) * 100 + 40);
  $(this).css('top', top + 'px');
  $(this).css('left', left + 'px');

  });
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo23ffwe/)

Note: [Math.random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) returns a number [0,1) ie can be 0, cannot be 1.
So, to get e.g. 1 to 6, just multiply by 6 and add 1, and round

```
var oneTosix = Math.round((Math.random() * 6)); // gives 0-5  
oneTosix += 1; // gives 1-6
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I just try to be helpful... :/